# How to get the element's other event handlers in Angular 1.x link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs, event-handling

I am dealing with two attributes in angular that handles both Enter key press event and Blur event of an input element which are both calling the same method of the scope:

```
<input type="number" ng-enter="doSomeThing()" ng-blur="doSomething()" />
```

The problem with this setup is that the Enter keypress event also triggers the Blur event almost at the same time so this caused EF concurrency error on the server. So to solve the issue, I had to make it so the method gets called only once. By the way, ngEnter is a custom directive:

```
myApp.directive('ngEnter', function () {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.ngEnter);
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };

    link.$inject = ["scope", "element", "attrs"];

    return {
        link: link
    }

});
```

I was able to cancel out the blur event by calling the `element.off('blur')` inside the keypress function as follows:

```
if (attrs.ngBlur && attrs.ngBlur == attrs.ngEnter) {
    element.off('blur');
}
```

but the problem now is the blur handler in the element is gone so I had to re-bind the handler to the blur event but  the element doesn't have the list of events. I tried `jQuery._data(element, "events" );` but it doesn't return anything, even the element's `data` is not defined. `element.off('blur')` worked so the handler must be there somewhere but where or how should I get access to those handlers? Does Angular store those handlers differently compared to Jquery?

Comment: So why do you need the `ngEnter` at all since the blur gets triggered anyway?

Comment: Hrm, you're right. I didn't think about that. I removed `ng-enter` and there is an error "An invalid form control with name='' is not focusable". Maybe it was set to avoid that error. I'll look into it... Thanks @charlietfl.